# React Native: How do I style my button to so it's in the bottom right corner of the screen and make it smaller?

Tags: react-native

I would like my button (the blue block across the screen) to be much smaller and in the bottom right corner of the screen. How do I do this with styling in react-native?

Here is my button at the moment:
[image]
App.js

```
render() {
   return (
     <View>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
     <Text>Plan Name:     </Text>
      <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'black', width: 120, borderWidth: 0.8}}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
      value={this.state.text}/>
      </View>  
      <MyDatePicker/>
      <Button style={{ width: 50, alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
     title="Add Plan"
     onPress={() =>
       this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen')}>
       </Button>
       </View>
     )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to be right of the `button` that is hidden if so you can give it a `flexDirection` of `row` and give `flex` to each wrapper so that it adjust itself
something like this.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
   <View style={{flex: 0.8}}><Button></Button></View>
   <View style={{ flex: 0.2}}><Button></Button></View>
</View>
```

If you want it to be on separate line below the `button` that is hidden you can do

```
<View>
  <Button style={{ width: 50, alignSelf: "flex-end" }}></Button>
</View>
```

and you can adjust the `width` accordingly.

You can update your `render` function as

```
render() {
   return (
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
     <Text>Plan Name:     </Text>
      <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'black', width: 120, borderWidth: 0.8}}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
      value={this.state.text}/>
      </View>  
      <MyDatePicker/>
      <View style={{ width: 50, alignSelf: "flex-end">
        <Button
     title="Add Plan"
     onPress={() =>
       this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen')}>
       </Button>
      </View>

       </View>
     )
 }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to implement the second block of code you provided however the button is covering the calendar and isn't at the bottom of my page. Is there another way I can get it in the bottom right corner?

Comment: could you add snack for this. Without looking code it is hard

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question with the relevant code.

Comment: I've completed my project now but I used the styling you provided to help style my application. Thanks for your help!